# Github clone command - a couple of questions

Tags: github

Is it needed to use --recursive command after clone to make the repository work properly? (if it contains vendor folder)

After cloning the repository, there is a .git folder in the downloaded location - can I safely delete this?

And the last question - one time I cloned a repository I got a password ssh request...won't there be any traces of my password in the downloaded repository?

Many thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--recursive` flag is for initializing submodules if applicable.

Do not delete the .git directory as this is what makes your collections of files a "repository."

The password is either for authenticating to the Github servers or for you to use your SSH private key. Either way, it will not affect what's in the repository (in fact, you'll likely need to enter this password every time you push or pull to Github).

It sounds like you could stand to read up on some Git and SSH basics. A quick Google search returned [this list of Git tutorials](http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/). Additionally, [github:help](https://help.github.com/) is an invaluable resource for beginners on Github.

Comment: I obviously know what's password for. I've always used ssh authentication to push/pull to my repositories, but to repositories of other users?

Comment: Do you mean pushing to/pulling from repositories owned by other Github users? If so, then yes, you will still need to authenticate to the Github servers as that is where the repository is hosted. They do additional checks on their end to make sure your account has permission to access the repository.